# Arduino Autonmous car if statements (ultrasonic)

Tags: c++, if-statement, arduino

I have run into a problem while creating the if statements for the autonomous car. The car skips most of the if statements and immeaditly goes to the else statement. The sensors give of the right values. Is it because i use "else if" statements or something else? The car is supposed to react to its surroundings, so i had to give it many if statements as possible. But instead it just does the last bit where it goes backwards waits goes backwards left and backwards right. So my question is do i have to add more if statements so it reacts better to its surroundings or is there more to it? Here is the code of the if statements:

```
  if (sensors[0] >= 50 ) { //if the distance of the front sensor is greater than 50cm, than set Fwd true. Otherwise its false.
    Fwd = true;
  } else {
    Fwd = false;
  }
  delay(50);
  if ((Fwd == true) && (sensors[1] > 50) && (sensors[2] > 50)) {
    fwd();
  } else if ((Fwd == true) && (sensors[1] < 50)) {
    fwdRight();
  } else if ((Fwd == true) && (sensors[2] < 50)) {
    fwdLeft();
  } else if ((Fwd == false) && (sensors[1] < 50) && (sensors[2] < 50)) {
    Stp();
  } else if ((Fwd == false) && (sensors[1] < 50)) {
    bwdRight();
  } else if ((Fwd == false) && sensors[2] < 50) {
    bwdRight();
  } else {
    Stp();
    delay(1000);
    bwd();
    delay(500);
    bwdLeft();
    delay(500);
    bwdRight();
  }
```

Comment: Could you describe what is under sensors[0] and 1 & 2 ? Because each time you compare different indexes. I mean first if compares with sensor 0 other are comparing with 1 & 2

Comment: You have not covered cases when distance is exactly == 50.

Comment: just use a ready to use code like this: http://wiki.keyestudio.com/index.php/Ks0192_keyestudio_4WD_Bluetooth_Multi-functional_Car

Comment: @DawidDrozd sensors[0] is the front sensor, 1 is the left and 2 is the right sensor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by tidying up your code, and it may be obvious where things may be going wrong. For example, you are calling multiple checks to `Fwd` by doing:

```cpp
if ((Fwd == true) && ... ) {
    ...
} else if ((Fwd == true) && ... ) {
    ...
} else if ((Fwd == true) && ... ) {
    ... 
} else if ((Fwd == false) && ... ) {
    ...
} else if ((Fwd == false) && ... ) {
    ...
}
```

This uses up valuable resources in your program memory. It would be much more efficient to do a single check, and evaluate from there:

```cpp
if (Fwd){
    // Check sensor conditions here
} else {
    // Check more sensor conditions here
}
```

In fact, you could probably omit the `Fwd` variable (unless you are using it elsewhere) altogether, saving you more memory space:

```cpp
// Check whether to go forward or backwards.
// >= 50 - forward
// <  50 - backward
if (sensors[0] >= 50) {
    // Check sensor conditions here 
} else {
    // Check more sensor conditions here
}
```

Overall, you could end up with something like:

```cpp
// Check whether to go forward or backwards.
// >= 50 - forward
// <  50 - backward
if (sensors[0] >= 50) {
    // Going forward, but which direction?
    if (sensors[1] < 50) {
        fwdRight();
    } else if (sensors[2] < 50) {
        fwdLeft();
    } else {
        // sensors[1] >= 50 AND sensors[2] >= 50
        // Going straight forward
        fwd();
    }
} else {
    // Check backward sensor conditions here
}
```

This answer might not directly answer your question, but it should help you diagnose better what is going on.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try and use it and see what happens.